# How can I run a workflow on all the documents which are already available in the document library?

Tags: workflow

How can I run a workflow on all the documents which are already available in the document library?

(for example a workflow that change the permissions of all the available documents in my library)

Answer (score 1):

If you work with SharePoint Designer 2013, then you can create Site Workflow ([see video](http://sharepoint-videos.com/sp10create-a-site-workflow-and-modify-its-form-using-infopath/), how to create sample site workflow), query all documents in library, then create loop and set permissions for each document individually.

If you work with SharePoint Designer 2010, unfortunately it doesn't support loops, so you can't iterate through all documents and set permissions individually. But if you need set permissions for all documents in the document library, you can set it on the Library level. Just configure SharePoint security group and add users to this group by workflow. I'm not sure there is standard workflow action for such purpose, but you can use free [codeplex custom action](http://natalyavoskresenskay.codeplex.com/)
Another option is to use [iLove SharePoint PowerShell Workflow Action](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/), using PowerShell script you can do anything you need.

You also can user Nintex Workflow, it supports loops, so you actions will be the same as with SharePoint Designer 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases where I needed to do this, I created a simple trigger column of type number. The default value is zero. In my workflow, I add a new first step that if the field equals 1 contine on else end the workflow and publish it. I then go into datasheet view and set the trigger column to 1 for all the documents I need to run the workflow on.

Once they've all processed, I delete that step in the workflow and delete the column.